# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when printing out a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

So I have a list of email address and I want to print them out so I attempted to do something like this:

```
for i in emails:
    print emails[i]
```

But when I do this I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Which is strange to me because when I write:

```
for i in emails:
    print emails[1]
```

It prints out the first email in the list, if it can print out when I specify a number why can't it print when I set it to "i"?

Comment: because `i` becomes the first element in the list, not a counter

Comment: How this code fragment behaves depends entirely upon the type of `emails`, which you haven't shown. Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program which demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Use names that make sense. The loop variable in a Python `for` loop is not an index, so it makes no sense to name it `i` The fact that you named it like an index has confused you into thinking it *is* an index. But it is not magically an index because you named it `i`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for email in emails:
    print email
```

Fortunately it's not JavaScript 5...

In JS 6 it would be something like:

```
for (email of emails) {
    console.log (email);
}
```

Comment: How is JS relevant here?

Comment: OP uses the meaning of 'in' as it is in JS. Many programmers programmed a website in JS, since JS is really a commodity these days, so I guessed that's where OP's confusion comes from. Think it's good to mention this difference explicitly, since otherwise it may still be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for anyone who will have the same problem I need to convert to a str and use i in range w/ the length of the list:

```
for i in range (0,len(emails)):
    print (str(emails[i]))
```

Comment: doing this with `range` is very un-Pythonic. You should use `for in in emails` like you had it.